# vue.js: Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, cors, nestjs

I am encountering an issue with Firebase Auth that seems to be related to the "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" header. The error message in the console is as follows:
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.

I am using Vue.js on the frontend and Nest.js on the backend. I am trying this on localhost.

This is the code that is causing the problem:

```
import { signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth'
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  const providers = new GoogleAuthProvider()
  signInWithPopup(getAuth(), providers)
    .then(() => {
      router.push({ name: 'home' })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error')
      console.log(error)
      alert(error.message)
    })
}
```

I click on 'Login,' then choose 'Sign in with Google.' It opens the popup, and I get the following error two times in the console:

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call. firebase_auth.js?v=99e2f81e:6512 
poll @ firebase_auth.js?v=99e2f81e:6512
show less
```

The popup opens, I click on my user, and I am successfully logged in through Google. Everything works perfectly, but I get two additional errors, the same as above.
Everything works perfectly, and nothing breaks, but I still encounter these errors in my console. How can I fix them?

I expect to be logged in without errors. I've tried all the fixes I could find on the first page of Google, but nothing has helped.